# How to open Rscript quickly and efficiently such as draging it from folder

Tags: r, rstudio

If I want to open a Rscript in Rstudio, I could only

1.click 'file' 'open file'

2.choose the script path

3.find out the script I need in that folder

I think it is not efficient.

Could Rstudio can drag script just like Matlab?

Comment: Are you a windows user?

Comment: see https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/9062

Comment: Yes, I am using windows. The issue about that seems still no answers (sadly)

Comment: This is more of a feature request for Rstudio than anything else. I voted to close this question as it is not something people here can do anything about.

Comment: In Windows Explorer: right click on the file, select "Open With ...", select RStudio, and it is now open in an editing pane in the RStudio IDE. While I couldn't drag-and-drop it (something I don't typically do anyway), I don't find right-click and open-with to be very onerous. If your instance of windows does not list RStudio in the "open with" context menu, then that's a different question, and (1) more appropriate for superuser.com, but really (2) it has been documented in so many blogs and howtos and such as to be a frequently _answered_ question.